# How to configure the rules of a Firebase project to be safe?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, rules

Hi I have the Firebase project, and when I create the databases, I create some rules for testing.
Now, they expire, and they close my project.
It is my first time working with Firebase projects, and I have no experience. I show you how I have defined the rules for both Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database.
The project is an application in which users can register and leave their comments.
How should I set the rules for my databases to be secure?
How should I write my rules code?
I was absent from my project for a few days and they wrote to me from Google, which closes my project in two days. I have looked for information, but I do not know how to create the rules so that they are correct and my project also works

***I EDIT MY QUESTION to add details***

In my application I only want registered users to be able to write comments.

The alert that Firebase shows me is the following:

"Its security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify or delete data from its database."

The databases are empty, so there are no records yet.

Can you help me? Firebase will close my project if I don't write the rules right, the rules shouldn't be public.

I read the [documentation that Firebase offers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#allow-all), but I don't really understand how to create my rules.

They show something like this, for authenticated users:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And on the other hand they show these rules:

```
**// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}**
```

I don't know which one I should use exactly, and how I should write them, so that in my React Native app users can leave feedback.

Can you help me ?

I show the code of the rules of my databases

```
//REALTIME DATABASE
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}


//CLOUD FIRESTORE
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 9, 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't give more details on how is your database structured  (Firestore or the Realtime Databaqse BTW?) and which kind of access rights you want to implement ("an application in which users can register and leave their comments" is too vague)?

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec , I'll edit the question. I just want the users registered in the app to write to the database. the DB is still empty

Comment: Please have a look to the solutions provided below and please let us know if they works for you or not in order to look further.

Comment: Continue writing Thanks for your support @NibrassH , At the moment that does not work for me

Comment: I posted an answer below, please have a look into it and let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following rule where only authenticated users can write and read to the database.

***For Cloud Firestore:***

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
  }
}
```

***For Realtime Database:***

```
// Only authenticated users can access/write data
{
“rules”: {
“.read”: “auth != null”,
“.write”: “auth != null”
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed them to the ones you have put, but you will see that they only have a change compared to mine (^). If it works, I will accept your answer as good @NibrassH

Comment: I have a question, are these the Cloud Firestore rules or are they Realtime Database rules? Thanks @NibrassN

Comment: No, these are for Cloud Firestore, I  have updated the answer adding also for Realtime Databases. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need to allow only authenticated users to access resource. From you code above

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The above will allow anybody to read and write to the database even to unauthenticated users.

for firestore as you can see the rules state that it should only allow full priviledge read and write to cloud firestore if only the date has not passed (2020,9,2)

VISIT the link [To learn more about firebase database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

and visit

[to learn about firestore rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

You can use firebase authentication for your users then if they are authenticated they can access the database.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking through experience, there are two main ways of securing your data:

1. Set a field in the document such as "userID" and only allow CRUD when the auth.uid value matches this field.
2. Use the collection-document-collection nature of cloud firestore and write a rule where you allow a user to CRUD all of their own collection. E.g.

```js
match /users/{userID}{
    allow read: if request.auth.uid ==userID;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    match /userDocs/{docID}{
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userID;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support @CRUD DS .   , should I write the rules as you show me?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso I cannot advice on that as it depends on your project requirement. Kindly use these two methods and experiment around. You can do it!